# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS (what can cause this)

Tags: java, android

hi something happened to my project. I worked day after night, the project is well going. before going to rest i re run the app and it was fine. when i try to run app next day it started to give this error

```
09/30 07:34:10: Launching 'app' on Pixel 4 API 28.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\amete\Documents\AssistX\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113'
```

what can cause this kind of failiure

Comment: Have define any `abi` in build.gradle?

Comment: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS is when you are trying to install an app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for your cpu architecture. For example if you compiled an app for armv7 and are trying to install it on an emulator that uses the Intel architecture instead it will not work. -  make sure your have all supported architecture ('armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64')  added in your project

Comment: nope didnt define any abi manually.

Comment: ok. i got the idea but dont know how to adjust it to my architecture configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS** is when you are trying to install an app that has native libraries and it doesn't have a native library for your cpu architecture. For example if you compiled an app for armv7 and are trying to install it on an emulator that uses the Intel architecture instead it will not work. - make sure your have all supported architecture added in your project

Add `ndk.filters` in your `app/build.gradle` files

```
  compileSdkVersion 30
   defaultConfig {
       appId "com.example.64bit"
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 30
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
```

Refer official docs for [64-bit support](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#build-with-64-bit) or the [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E96vmWkUdgA)

Comment: nope... not worked, digging in to referals