# Making Vuforia Unity projects for 32-bit devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, vuzix

I would like to develop an AR app through Vuforia and Unity for a 32-bit device, the Vuzix Blade 2. In order to make the app compatible with 32-bit devices, I had to enable ARMv7. I had a previous issue with the app not working with 32-bit devices, missing some libraries for 32-bit operations [according to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69386264/install-failed-no-matching-abis-what-can-cause-this):

[image]

This is the error I got:

> Note that you’re currently targeting 32-bit (ARMv7) and ARCore is removing support for 32-bit only apps on 64-bit devices. This removed support might result into a black screen. Please target also 64-bit (ARM64) if your app is used on 64-bit devices.

[image]

Consulting the [Vuzix Blade 2 documentation](https://intercom.help/vuzix/en/articles/6390155-unity-project-settings) suggested that ARMv7 is necessary.

[image]

As a result I consulted [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790615/this-app-includes-the-following-32-bit-only-armeabi-v7a-libraries-oculus-dev) which suggested ARM64 also be activated. The problem persisted.

My next attempt was to follow a [Vuforia tutorial](https://medium.com/@patrick_scheper/how-to-fix-the-black-screen-issue-on-android-when-using-vuforia-engine-51c59cc4c9d8) which suggested either reinstalling a custom, depreciated ARCore, or removing ARCore entirely. The link in question for the ARCore is badly depreciated.

I attempted to install the custom, depreciated ARCore. This was the result:

> Found plugins with same names, Assets/Plugins/Android/arcore_client.aar and Packages/com.google.ar.core.arfoundation.extensions/Runtime/Plugins/arcore_client.aar. Delete the one of the duplicate plugins.
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidPluginImporterExtension:CheckFileCollisions (string,string[])
> UnityEditorInternal.PluginsHelper:CheckFileCollisions (UnityEditor.BuildTarget,string[])
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

[image]

And now I am unsure which plugin to delete.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: ARCore is not available on Vuzix devices (it does not matter if 32 or 64 bit builds). This warning is likely for old apps built for standard mobile devices. What happens if you ignore the warning?

Comment: It gave me an error, not a warning. That is why I cannot ignore it. I will post a picture of the warning, which I initially thought was unnecessary due to the scope of this question.

Comment: As mentioned above this is a device which does not support ARCore thus an error related to ARCore is likely inappropriate. I would reach to the Vuforia team via the issue tracker here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine

Comment: Beside this please note that the Vuzix Blade 2 is not on the list of recommended devices (https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/recommended-devices). This means that it has not been tested by the Vuforia team and you might discover more issues along the way.

Comment: There is some information on how to handle ARCore here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/using-arcore-vuforia-engine I would try to set ARCore requirement to DON’T USE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Vuforia into Unity and double-checking the license used for Vuforia proved effective in solving the issue.

If you are having the same issue, check if the version of Vuforia used is properly installed.